# Cast a nullable DateTime in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Using EF6 I want to get all objects of the year 2019 from my database CALENDRIER, but EF6 generates nullables DateTimes "DateTime?" instead of usual DateTimes. Because I want only the year, I could use the Year field from the DateTime to filter my List, but it isn't available with a nullable DateTime. Basically I want to use it like this :

```
_db.CALENDRIERs.Where(c => c.CALE_DATE.Year == year).ToList();
```

But I get the following error :

> 'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Year' and no accessible extension method 'Year' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found...

How can I cast them implicitely inside my lambda expression ?

Comment: `c.CALE_DATE.Year` => `c.CALE_DATE?.Year`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First check to see if CALE_DATE has a value, and then use the .Value

```
_db.CALENDRIERs.Where(c => c.CALE_DATE.HasValue && c.CALE_DATE.Value.Year == year).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the `Value` field of the nullable type:

```
DateTime? nullableDt = DateTime.Now;
int year = nullableDt.Value.Year;
```

Comment: Wow thanks it was simplier than I thought, it works !

Comment: You're welcome! As others have suggested, be sure to check if the Value exists before directly accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check whether the DateTime object is not null i.e. it has value and then you can fetch the Year property from it

`_db.CALENDRIERs.Where(c => c.CALE_DATE.HasValue && c.CALE_DATE.Year == year).ToList();`

Comment: I think the `c.CALE_DATE.Year` is going to cause the same exact problem as reported in the question.It's still a `DateTime?` even after it's been checked for null.

Comment: If I understood it correctly then you are saying that if an DateTime object is null then it will throw exception when we check for `c.CALE_DATE.Year  == year` which is correct. But as per above line of code we first check for c.CALE_DATE.HasValue we make sure that the object is not null i.e. it has some value and only then we are checking if the YEAR property of c.CALE_DATE matches to `year` value. I think it will work